# Please help me to fix html div width in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok i coded some html pages. I integrated a jQuery slider there. Slider name orbit slider.
My site use fluid layout. If you minimize the page vertically, you can see the right corner images moving left side.

But i have some problem. I want to move the right side slider navigation too when the user shrink the page vertically.

The problem is i couldn't apply 100% width in the slider. Slider automatically create the width based on image size. I don't know how to change it to 100% width.
You can check the slider in this page.

[Click here to see the page](http://girisoft.net/louisa/)

This is my javascript file.

[Javascript file](http://girisoft.net/louisa/js/jquery.orbit-1.2.3.min.js)

This is the place where the javascript uses width.

```
var b = 0,
p = 0,
h, v, u, f = d(this).addClass("orbit"),
c = f.wrap('<div class="orbit-wrapper" />').parent();
f.add(h).width("1px").height("1px");
var e = f.children("img, a, div");
e.each(function () {
    var a = d(this),
    b = a.width(),
    a = a.height();
    b > f.width() && (f.add(c).width(b), h = f.width());
    a > f.height() && (f.add(c).height(a), v = f.height());
    p++
});
```

You can check it in the javascript file. I want the width 100%. Please give me some idea. Thanks

Comment: 1+ That is a good question. Provided code, working sample... I have to go out now otherwise would have helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you force the slider with to be 100&% by using the !important css?
I tried it via firebug and it seemed to work.

example change your css to:

```
.orbit-wrapper:
{
    width: 100% !important;
}
```